# How to find mean of a specific group of data in R and present them with geom line

Tags: mysql, r

Here I have two datasets, the one of the professor with `id=900264` and the one of the students who are taught by that professor. The values of `timearriving` and `timeA` were date and time (`timeA`column shows the time they should have checked in while `timearriving` shows the time they actually arrived). In order to calculate them in column `late` I had to convert them in numerical values. Since I want to come in conclusion that "If the professor is late so are the students" I have to calculate also the average of the column `late` in students dataset. So, my question is: how can I calculate the average of how much late the students are each week in that subject?
The next thing I have to do is to connect both the `late` column in Teacher and the averages of how much late the students are in order to create the geom line and to come with a conclusion.

[This is a picture of students dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41enH.png)

[And this is the dataset of the teacher I have chosen from the main dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMjSm.png)

This is what i got from teacher1 table:

```
structure(list(number = c(214980L, 215708L, 216388L, 217106L, 
217250L, 217808L, 217952L, 218640L, 218788L, 219397L, 219541L, 
220273L, 220419L, 221050L, 221196L, 221927L, 222073L, 222697L, 
222843L, 223730L, 224362L, 225241L, 225387L, 226015L, 226161L, 
226901L, 227047L), id = c(900264L, 900264L, 900264L, 900264L, 
900264L, 900264L, 900264L, 900264L, 900264L, 900264L, 900264L, 
900264L, 900264L, 900264L, 900264L, 900264L, 900264L, 900264L, 
900264L, 900264L, 900264L, 900264L, 900264L, 900264L, 900264L, 
900264L, 900264L), location = c("1001.18", "1001.18", "1001.18", 
"1001.18", "1001.18", "1001.18", "1001.18", "1001.18", "1001.18", 
"1001.18", "1001.18", "1001.18", "1001.18", "1001.18", "1001.18", 
"1001.18", "1001.18", "1001.18", "1001.18", "1001.18", "1001.18", 
"1001.18", "1001.18", "1001.18", "1001.18", "1001.18", "1001.18"
), timearriving = c(NA, 1474530906, 1475136022, 1475656815, 1475741027, 
NA, 1476345704, 1476864244, 1476950392, 1477468866, 1477555529, 
1478074160, 1478160545, 1478678754, 1478765026, 1479283730, 1479370066, 
1479888520, 1479974860, 1480579139, NA, 1481703070, 1481789322, 
1482306957, 1482393708, 1482912383, 1482999124), timeleaving = c(NA, 
1474538398, 1475142846, 1475661187, 1475747579, NA, 1476352305, 
1476871044, 1476957017, 1477475465, 1477562164, 1478080666, 1478167193, 
1478685317, 1478771604, 1479290120, 1479376513, 1479895013, 1479981498, 
1480586054, NA, 1481709363, 1481795865, 1482314055, 1482400509, 
1482919625, NA), timeA = c(1473926400, 1474531200, 1475136000, 
1475654400, 1475740800, 1476259200, 1476345600, 1476864000, 1476950400, 
1477468800, 1477555200, 1478073600, 1478160000, 1478678400, 1478764800, 
1479283200, 1479369600, 1479888000, 1479974400, 1480579200, 1481097600, 
1481702400, 1481788800, 1482307200, 1482393600, 1482912000, 1482998400
), timeL = c(1473933600, 1474538400, 1475143200, 1475661600, 
1475748000, 1476266400, 1476352800, 1476871200, 1476957600, 1477476000, 
1477562400, 1478080800, 1478167200, 1478685600, 1478772000, 1479290400, 
1479376800, 1479895200, 1479981600, 1480586400, 1481104800, 1481709600, 
1481796000, 1482314400, 1482400800, 1482919200, 1483005600), 
    person = c("Teacher", "Teacher", "Teacher", "Teacher", "Teacher", 
    "Teacher", "Teacher", "Teacher", "Teacher", "Teacher", "Teacher", 
    "Teacher", "Teacher", "Teacher", "Teacher", "Teacher", "Teacher", 
    "Teacher", "Teacher", "Teacher", "Teacher", "Teacher", "Teacher", 
    "Teacher", "Teacher", "Teacher", "Teacher"), late = c(NA, 
    294, -22, -2415, -227, NA, -104, -244, 8, -66, -329, -560, 
    -545, -354, -226, -530, -466, -520, -460, 61, NA, -670, -522, 
    243, -108, -383, -724)), .Names = c("number", "id", "location", 
"timearriving", "timeleaving", "timeA", "timeL", "person", "late"
), row.names = c(NA, -27L), class = "data.frame")
```

This is a sample from students1:

```
     number     id location timearriving timeleaving      timeA      timeL  person late
1    214980 126214  1001.18           NA          NA 1473926400 1473933600 Student   NA
2    215269 126237  1001.18           NA          NA 1474272000 1474279200 Student   NA
3    215269 126226  1001.18   1474272103          NA 1474272000 1474279200 Student -103
4    215269 126196  1001.18           NA          NA 1474272000 1474279200 Student   NA
5    215393 126262  1001.18           NA          NA 1474293600 1474300800 Student   NA
6    215425 126118  1001.18           NA          NA 1474358400 1474365600 Student   NA
7    215565 126231  1001.18   1474444900          NA 1474444800 1474452000 Student -100
8    215565 126189  1001.18   1474444570          NA 1474444800 1474452000 Student  230
9    215687 126262  1001.18           NA          NA 1474466400 1474473600 Student   NA
10   215708 126611  1001.18           NA          NA 1474531200 1474538400 Student   NA
11   215708 126602  1001.18   1474531548          NA 1474531200 1474538400 Student -348
12   215708 126588  1001.18           NA          NA 1474531200 1474538400 Student   NA
13   215708 126564  1001.18           NA          NA 1474531200 1474538400 Student   NA
14   215708 126472  1001.18   1474531229          NA 1474531200 1474538400 Student  -29
15   215708 126394  1001.18   1474531757          NA 1474531200 1474538400 Student -557
16   215708 126392  1001.18   1474531562          NA 1474531200 1474538400 Student -362
17   215708 126391  1001.18   1474531554          NA 1474531200 1474538400 Student -354
18   215708 126367  1001.18   1474531110          NA 1474531200 1474538400 Student   90
19   215708 126365  1001.18           NA          NA 1474531200 1474538400 Student   NA
20   215708 126346  1001.18           NA          NA 1474531200 1474538400 Student   NA
21   215708 126342  1001.18   1474531551          NA 1474531200 1474538400 Student -351
22   215708 126303  1001.18   1474531108          NA 1474531200 1474538400 Student   92
23   215708 126299  1001.18   1474531596          NA 1474531200 1474538400 Student -396
24   215708 126285  1001.18   1474531556          NA 1474531200 1474538400 Student -356
25   215708 126270  1001.18           NA          NA 1474531200 1474538400 Student   NA
26   215708 126234  1001.18   1474530946          NA 1474531200 1474538400 Student  254
27   215708 126227  1001.18           NA          NA 1474531200 1474538400 Student   NA
28   215708 126214  1001.18           NA          NA 1474531200 1474538400 Student   NA
29   215843 126635  1001.18           NA          NA 1474617600 1474624800 Student   NA
30   215843 126603  1001.18           NA          NA 1474617600 1474624800 Student   NA
31   215843 126503  1001.18   1474617503          NA 1474617600 1474624800 Student   97
32   215843 126470  1001.18   1474617717          NA 1474617600 1474624800 Student -117
33   215843 126448  1001.18   1474617489          NA 1474617600 1474624800 Student  111
34   215843 126447  1001.18   1474617505          NA 1474617600 1474624800 Student   95
35   215843 126445  1001.18           NA          NA 1474617600 1474624800 Student   NA
36   215843 126438  1001.18   1474617691          NA 1474617600 1474624800 Student  -91
37   215843 126381  1001.18   1474617746          NA 1474617600 1474624800 Student -146
38   215843 126363  1001.18   1474617757          NA 1474617600 1474624800 Student -157
39   215843 126341  1001.18           NA          NA 1474617600 1474624800 Student   NA
40   215843 126311  1001.18           NA          NA 1474617600 1474624800 Student   NA
41   215843 126292  1001.18   1474617715          NA 1474617600 1474624800 Student -115
42   215843 126288  1001.18   1474617400          NA 1474617600 1474624800 Student  200
43   215843 126246  1001.18   1474617398          NA 1474617600 1474624800 Student  202
44   215843 126240  1001.18           NA          NA 1474617600 1474624800 Student   NA
45   215843 126239  1001.18           NA          NA 1474617600 1474624800 Student   NA
46   215920 126585  1001.18           NA          NA 1474639200 1474646400 Student   NA
47   215920 126525  1001.18   1474639276          NA 1474639200 1474646400 Student  -76
48   215920 126469  1001.18   1474639711          NA 1474639200 1474646400 Student -511
49   215920 126455  1001.18           NA          NA 1474639200 1474646400 Student   NA
50   215920 126410  1001.18           NA          NA 1474639200 1474646400 Student   NA
51   215920 126364  1001.18           NA          NA 1474639200 1474646400 Student   NA
52   215920 126295  1001.18   1474638987          NA 1474639200 1474646400 Student  213
53   215936 126662  1001.18           NA          NA 1474876800 1474884000 Student   NA
54   215936 126610  1001.18   1474876681          NA 1474876800 1474884000 Student  119
55   215936 126552  1001.18           NA          NA 1474876800 1474884000 Student   NA
56   215936 126452  1001.18   1474876715          NA 1474876800 1474884000 Student   85
57   215936 126421  1001.18           NA          NA 1474876800 1474884000 Student   NA
58   215936 126417  1001.18           NA          NA 1474876800 1474884000 Student   NA
59   215936 126406  1001.18   1474876706          NA 1474876800 1474884000 Student   94
60   215936 126343  1001.18   1474876696          NA 1474876800 1474884000 Student  104
61   215936 126319  1001.18   1474877323          NA 1474876800 1474884000 Student -523
62   215936 126301  1001.18   1474876691          NA 1474876800 1474884000 Student  109
63   215936 126238  1001.18   1474877324          NA 1474876800 1474884000 Student -524
64   215936 126237  1001.18   1474876703          NA 1474876800 1474884000 Student   97
65   215936 126226  1001.18           NA          NA 1474876800 1474884000 Student   NA
66   215936 126196  1001.18   1474876687          NA 1474876800 1474884000 Student  113
67   215936 126191  1001.18   1474877284          NA 1474876800 1474884000 Student -484
68   215936 126187  1001.18   1474876633          NA 1474876800 1474884000 Student  167
69   216106 126118  1001.18           NA          NA 1474963200 1474970400 Student   NA
70   216246 126614  1001.18   1475049139          NA 1475049600 1475056800 Student  461
71   216246 126585  1001.18   1475049880          NA 1475049600 1475056800 Student -280
72   216246 126231  1001.18   1475049589          NA 1475049600 1475056800 Student   11
73   216388 126691  1001.18   1475136323          NA 1475136000 1475143200 Student -323
74   216388 126611  1001.18   1475136513          NA 1475136000 1475143200 Student -513
75   216388 126602  1001.18   1475136319          NA 1475136000 1475143200 Student -319
76   216388 126588  1001.18           NA          NA 1475136000 1475143200 Student   NA
77   216388 126582  1001.18           NA          NA 1475136000 1475143200 Student   NA
78   216388 126564  1001.18           NA          NA 1475136000 1475143200 Student   NA
79   216388 126472  1001.18   1475135769          NA 1475136000 1475143200 Student  231
80   216388 126457  1001.18   1475136385          NA 1475136000 1475143200 Student -385
81   216388 126400  1001.18           NA          NA 1475136000 1475143200 Student   NA
82   216388 126394  1001.18   1475135568          NA 1475136000 1475143200 Student  432
83   216388 126392  1001.18   1475136124          NA 1475136000 1475143200 Student -124
84   216388 126367  1001.18   1475135535          NA 1475136000 1475143200 Student  465
85   216388 126365  1001.18   1475136201          NA 1475136000 1475143200 Student -201
86   216388 126346  1001.18   1475136389          NA 1475136000 1475143200 Student -389
87   216388 126342  1001.18   1475135526          NA 1475136000 1475143200 Student  474
88   216388 126337  1001.18   1475135875          NA 1475136000 1475143200 Student  125
89   216388 126303  1001.18   1475135797          NA 1475136000 1475143200 Student  203
90   216388 126285  1001.18   1475136131          NA 1475136000 1475143200 Student -131
91   216388 126270  1001.18           NA          NA 1475136000 1475143200 Student   NA
92   216388 126234  1001.18   1475135777          NA 1475136000 1475143200 Student  223
93   216388 126227  1001.18   1475136229          NA 1475136000 1475143200 Student -229
94   216388 126223  1001.18   1475135796          NA 1475136000 1475143200 Student  204
95   216388 126214  1001.18   1475135925          NA 1475136000 1475143200 Student   75
96   216540 126635  1001.18           NA          NA 1475222400 1475229600 Student   NA
97   216540 126603  1001.18   1475222861          NA 1475222400 1475229600 Student -461
98   216540 126503  1001.18           NA          NA 1475222400 1475229600 Student   NA
99   216540 126470  1001.18   1475222314          NA 1475222400 1475229600 Student   86
100  216540 126448  1001.18           NA          NA 1475222400 1475229600 Student   NA
101  216540 126447  1001.18           NA          NA 1475222400 1475229600 Student   NA
102  216540 126445  1001.18   1475222248          NA 1475222400 1475229600 Student  152
103  216540 126438  1001.18   1475222316          NA 1475222400 1475229600 Student   84
104  216540 126381  1001.18   1475222621          NA 1475222400 1475229600 Student -221
105  216540 126363  1001.18   1475222737          NA 1475222400 1475229600 Student -337
106  216540 126341  1001.18   1475222732          NA 1475222400 1475229600 Student -332
107  216540 126311  1001.18           NA          NA 1475222400 1475229600 Student   NA
108  216540 126292  1001.18   1475222371          NA 1475222400 1475229600 Student   29
109  216540 126288  1001.18   1475222106          NA 1475222400 1475229600 Student  294
110  216540 126246  1001.18   1475222112          NA 1475222400 1475229600 Student  288
111  216540 126240  1001.18   1475222749          NA 1475222400 1475229600 Student -349
```

Comment: in the future, attach your data set instead of attaching an image so that we may work with your data. also, I don't see any date variable in your data set...what do you mean by how late each student is each week in a subject...is all the data for a week and a subject in just one dataframe?

Comment: use `dput()` on you data so we can work with it.

Comment: Please edit the question as suggested to include the data as plain text, not images, so users can copy/paste it.

Comment: I did as you said, but if you can tell me how can I attach the students1 table because I was unable to do so since it has 1409 entries.

Comment: Did you forget the *student1* dataset? Please also show few rows of desired result which you can use to illustrate your point. Textual explanation is harder to understand.

Comment: I edited it again and now I have shown a sample of the _student1_  dataset